# can I evaluate multiple cells at the same time?

Tags: performance-tuning, evaluation

my laptop has 2 cores, can I assign a core to evaluate one code, and the other core for another code in parallel instead of evaluating in sequence?
thanks

Comment: You can assign a separate kernel to separate notebooks  using the Evaluation menu (if your license allows this). They are totally separate and don't share any variables. For parallelization in one notebook you may want to read this [guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ParallelComputing.html).